# MLS Integration (RETSBond RI or?)

Tags: php, web-services, api

I'm looking Specifically for some detailed information on [RETSBond Integrator (RI)](http://retsbond.com/ri/faq) or something similar. Has anyone used it? Drawbacks? benefits?

What I need is something that provides a PHP API out of the box or some kind of RPC exposure. This thing seems to provide an API for batching the MLS server and putting in my own DB which is acceptable although ideally I'd prefer something totally external. Do any MLS services provide that that you are aware of?

I realize this is somewhat subjective but I'm looking for a starting point on different services/vendors to research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.  Have you looked at the client and server implementations at rets.org?

[VieleRets](http://www.crt.realtors.org/projects/rets/viele/) is a PHP RETS client/server application that can both query a RETS datasource and mirror an existing DB. It is open source.  If you said a little bit more about what you are trying to accomplish, might be able to provide other advice.

Comment: I did  take a look at those after your suggestion. Viele should fit the need. Id like to ask more specific questions but i dont have details on the full feature set the client wants to implement, though i assume typical search/browsing of a specific universe is about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [retsCloud.com](http://retscloud.com) They do the work for you and it's something like $20 a month.

Comment: This project has passed but thanks for the info.. it wil com in handy in the future!